# Смена цвета строки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Как программно можно менять цвет строки в `DataGrid`? Например, приходит новое сообщение и нужная строка выделяется определенным цветом.

Comment: Использовать `DataGrid` жизненно необходимо?

Comment: @Андрей а что еще можно использовать? DataGrid содержит открытые заявки, которые считываются из базы и при клике на такую заявку открывается чат. Можно конечно сделать редактируя шаблон ListBox, но я подумал, что можно просто программно как-нибудь поменять.

Comment: @Идентикон можно еще использовать `ListView`

Comment: но как мне кажется, ваш вопрос решается простым стилем, если у вас есть свойство которое и будет сигнализировать о цвете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Решение подсмотрено здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18053281/6766879)

Вам потребуется в VM-классе заявки добавить свойство показывающее ее "активность", я назвал его `IsActive`.
Тогда задача решается простым `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Requests}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рег. №" Binding="{Binding RegNum}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наименование" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, а что должно быть присвоено этому свойству InActive, чтобы срабатывал триггер или нет.

Comment: Это `bool`-свойство.  И, как видно из разметки, триггер срабатывает по значению `true`

Comment: Спасибо, сделал все работает.

Comment: @Идентикон, пожалуйста! Рад помочь.